# How to reopen the winapi window?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I have WinAPI application with menu. I click "Graphics" and choose open or draw. It doesn't matter what exactly. Then I close the child window. When I try to open it again, it doesn't work. Maybe I should put somewhere ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE). But I don't understand, where it should be. Maybe there is another solution

[main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fljKV.png)

**Here I'll put my code**:

Callbacks, which I use

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DrawProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            ...
        }
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK GraphProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            ...
        }
        break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            ...
        case WM_SIZE:
            ...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SoftwareMainProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case draw_plot:
            GraphClass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
            GraphClass.lpfnWndProc    = DrawProcedure;
            GraphClass.hInstance      = hInst;
            GraphClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
            GraphClass.lpszClassName = L"graphics";

            if (!RegisterClassW(&GraphClass))
            {
                return -1;
            }

            gr_draw = CreateWindow(L"graphics", L"DRAW", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 800, 700, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
            break;

        case open_plot:
            GraphClass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
            GraphClass.lpfnWndProc    = GraphProcedure;
            GraphClass.hInstance      = hInst;
            GraphClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
            GraphClass.lpszClassName = L"graphics";

            if (!RegisterClassW(&GraphClass))
            {
                return -1;
            }

            gr_open = CreateWindow(L"graphics", L"OPEN", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 800, 700, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
            break;
     
        case OnExitSoftware:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        ...
    }
    break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        MainWndAddMenus(hWnd);
        MainWndAddWidgets(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: // close mainwindow
        ExitSoftware();
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterClassW(&GraphClass)` doesn't work the second time, because the window class is already registered, because you already registered it the first time.

It returns false to tell you that it didn't work, then *your code* doesn't open the window. To reiterate: You told the computer, that if `RegisterClassW(&GraphClass)` doesn't work, then it shouldn't open the window.

**Solution**: Either register the window class the first time you use it (not every time), or register all the window classes when the program starts.

**Side question to think about:** Why did you tell the computer to do nothing if `RegisterClassW(&GraphClass)` doesn't work? If you told it to pop up a message box saying "RegisterClassW(&GraphClass) didn't work", you'd know where the problem was, because the message box would tell you.

Comment: I've understood the problem, but can you show, how can I improve it via code?

Comment: @dthedog you can register it only the first time, or you can register all your window classes when your program starts up. Which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: "how can I improve it via code" that's your job, this being a site for programmers

Comment: @user253751 I've done it using messagebox. Thanks!!

Comment: @dthedog you did what using messagebox?

Comment: @user253751 It now works for one thing. I can open either "draw" each time, or 
"open" after messagebox. If I open "draw" and close it, and then I open "open", it works draw again... [link](https://pastebin.com/3SjZymhM)

Comment: @dthedog ........ do you understand why that happens?

Comment: @user253751 till no. Trying to do smth else

Comment: @dthedog I want you to stop and think about this part until you understand why it does what it does, why `return -1;` makes the window not open, and why `MessageBoxA(hWnd, "error", "draw_err", MB_OK);` makes it show a messagebox and then open, and why you completely misunderstood what I said about the messagebox

Comment: @dthedog I rewrote the answre. Hopefully it is easier to understand

Comment: @dthedog I wonder if you have learned basic programming yet: the fact that each line of code is an instruction, and the computer runs instructions from top to bottom (most of the time). Is it possible you dove in over your head?

Comment: @user253751 I understand that it contains instructions, but here I still don't understand this process

Comment: @dthedog Just *writing* `MessageBox` in the code doesn't make a message box. What makes the message box appear is that the computer actually gets to the instruction that says MessageBox. If you write `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) MessageBox(blah blah);` it displays the message box 5 times because of the loop; if you write `if(1 + 1 == 3) MessageBox(blah blah);` it never displays it because 1+1 is 2. You get this, right? Everything I just said should be really obvious - if not then I suggest practicing the basics of programming (not with winapi)

Comment: I've understood it

Comment: @dthedog so it's the same with RegisterClassEx - every time the computer gets to the instruction that says RegisterClassEx it registers the class. Except, the second time, it doesn't, because it's already registered